# DB2 Nosql / MongoDB 'An operator that starts with $ is expected for projectid' error?

Tags: db2, mongodb-query

I have a list of documents with the structure:

```
{
  from:"string"
  to:"string"
  payload:{
    projectid:10000
  }
}
```

I want to delete all documents with payload.projectid set to 10000 using the java API.

From the command-line I write:

```
db.notifications.find({"payload":{"projectid":10000}})
```

Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An operator that starts with $ is expected for projectid.
```

A similar error arises if I delete, whether through cli or programmatically.

This works in normal mongoDB.

How do I delete in db2 nosql?

Java code (for your reference!):

```
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.append("to", "username");
    query.append("from", "username2");
    query.append("payload", new BasicDBObject().append("projectid", 10000));
    System.out.println(query); // prints out okay
    col.remove(query); //error
```

Comment: db.notifications.find({ "payload.projectid": { $in: [10000] } }); - obviously this is just in respect to the find, not sure about the delete :) - warning, I'm a mongo noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using dot notation to reference the sub-document field:

[Link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/)

In your case it would be:

```
db.notifications.find({"payload.projectid":10000})
```

In Java the find should look something like this:

```
DBCollection notifications = db.getCollection("notifications")
DBObject subdocumentQuery = new BasicDBObject("payload.projectid", 10000);
DBCursor subdocumentCursor = notifications.find(subdocumentQuery);
```